# Algorithm to Color Nodes Hierarchically

Tags: algorithm, graph, colors, color-palette

I have a network where the nodes are defined hierarchically (via [UN SITC coding](http://comtrade.un.org/db/mr/rfCommoditiesList.aspx?px=S2&cc=TOTAL)).  In my application, each node has four identifying digits of increasing hierachical specificity (for example, see product [7431](http://comtrade.un.org/db/mr/rfCommoditiesList.aspx?px=S2&cc=7431)) but the network that I've defined is not just the obvious hierachical structure.  What I'm trying to do is to color the nodes hierarchically, but lay them out according to my network calculation and see to what extent the two coincide.

Generally speaking, I am looking for a way to generate N color palettes which are as visually distinct as possible from one and other (obviously it's less and less effective as N grows) and then to divide them into sub-palettes until I reach the desired hierarchical depth.

Specifically, that would mean choosing 10 base colors for the first digit and generating  palettes of K<=10 colors for each of them where K is the number of possible values that the second digit can assume, and again for the third and fourth digit until I end up with all of the nodes colored according to their hierarchical information.  The greens are one type, and within them certain shades of green define certain families of nodes corresponding to visual likeness.

It seems like "Analagous" is the color property that I want to implement.  Would simply splitting up the hue parameter regularly in an HSV/HSL scheme accomplish this or is there a better way?

I'll be implementing it in Python but any algorithm should basically be language agnostic.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a smaller visual example showing what you're shooting for?

Answer (score 0):

I tackled a similar problem (likely an inverse of what you're doing) where I was comparing the spectral output of various images to determine an ordering based on similarity.

After many weeks of fiddling with the RGB cube of colors, I gave up and moved to HSV - and never looked back.  I would identify those Hues that define colors then permute based on that so that you don't have two kinda-yellow colors - rather, you'd start a x and then add multiples of k so that you'd have something like this:

```
x is red
x+k is yellow
x+2k is green
... so forth
```

Within this, I would subdivide and possibly permute the 'value' and 'saturation' by small amounts to increase the number of colors you have available to you.

If you end up converting between systems, I used [colorsys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html) with no issues.